# Winsock IRC client connects but does not send data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, winsock2

I'm using the code posted on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/126639f1-487d-4755-af1b-cfb8bb64bdf8 but it doesn't send data just like it says in the first post. How do I use WSAGetLastError() like it says in the solution to find out what's wrong?

I tried the following:

```
  void IRC::SendBuf(char* sendbuf)

  {

      int senderror = send(m_socket, sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf), MSG_OOB);      

     if(senderror == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            printf("Client: The test string sent: \"%s\"\n", sendbuf);
     }
     else {
            cout << "error is: " << senderror << ", WSAGetLastError: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;       
  printf("Client: The test string sent: \"%s\"\n", sendbuf);

  }
  }
```

And the output is: error is: 4, WSAGetLastError: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're evaluating the address of [WSAGetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741580%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of calling it. You need to add parenthesis in order to actually call that function:

```
void IRC::SendBuf(char* sendbuf)
{
    int senderror = send(m_socket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (senderror != SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Client: The test string sent: \"%s\"\n", sendbuf);
    } else {
        cout << "Error is: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The [send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740149%28VS.85%29.aspx) function returns the number of bytes written, not an error code. You need to test the return value against `SOCKET_ERROR`, as in the updated code above. In your case, `send()` tells that it successfully sent 4 bytes.

As you noted below, it only sends 4 bytes because that's the size of the `sendbuf` variable (it's a pointer, not a buffer). If the string in `sendbuf` is null-terminated, you can use `strlen()` instead. If it isn't, you probably should add a string length parameter to `IRC::SendBuf()` itself.

Comment: Now it prints 0. Shouldn't I get one of the codes listed here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx#winsock.wsaeshutdown_2

Comment: @thorvald, not necessarily. Error `0` means `no error`, i.e. everything went smoothly. What makes you think your previous socket call should have failed?

Comment: Because it didn't send anything to the server after connecting so I figured something went wrong. I'm using the code from this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/126639f1-487d-4755-af1b-cfb8bb64bdf8 but the original poster didn't say how he fixed the problem.

Comment: @thorvald, maybe you can update your question with that information (and the related code), so we can have a better idea of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Still the same problem. It doesn't send anything to the server and prints "Error is: 0".

Comment: Okay, I ran wireshark to find out what went wrong. It's sending only the first 4 letters so I think sizeof(sendbuf) is not right.